# How to fix proportions of output

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I have my OpenGL graphic where I'd like to fix proportions. What I actually have now.

While my form has normal proportions (like 4:3) everything looks nice. But when I re-size form to approx (20:2) image becomes outstretched (this effect I'd like to avoid).

---

**Normal proportions**

[image: normal proportions]

**Outstretched proportions**

[image: outstretched proportions]

I use shaders approach. **My matrices set-ups looks like:**

```
    projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(Width, Height, 10000f, -10000f);
    viewMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    modelMatrix = Matrix4.Scale(1.0f);
```

**When render:**

```
        viewMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationY((float)xrot) *
                     Matrix4.CreateRotationX((float)yrot) *
                     Matrix4.Scale((float)scale);

        program.SetValue(projectionMatrix);
        program.SetValue(viewMatrix);
        program.SetValue(modelMatrix);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must recreate and resubmit to OpenGL the projection matrix when the window's aspect ratio changes to reflect that.